# Is it considered appropriate to edit multiple answers of another user into a single answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

Sometimes, users post multiple answers to the same question. (Examples: [Boot taking forever with a 106 JBOD attached. - WARNING: Device /dev/xxx not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/690552/34039) and [Is dnf supported on Centos 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/630719/34039)) I think this is unnecessary and makes it more difficult to choose a solution, but perhaps it's just my pet peeve.

In the most egregious cases, an user posted up to 4 answers to their own questions. The answers are one-liners, low-quality, or similar to each other. (Example: [How to do a transparent compression of a folder on Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/720333/34039) and another question from the same user that has now been deleted.) It seems to me that an user doing so is just fishing for reputation, since each answer can be upvoted individually.

In these cases downvoting all answers is considered serial voting and thus reversed, so I flagged the answers for a moderator to see.

My question is: is it considered appropriate/respectful to clean up the question by editing multiple answers of another user to condense them into a single answer?

Comment: While 100% agreeing with you that this is bad practice from the OP. These sorts of Q/A are absolutely painful to read. But I wonder whether they would be less painful for the reader if all answers were merged. Particularly if, as the OP answered Kusa, answers are not related. Anyway, a mod covered those threads while suggesting the OP to merge, and did not authoritatively merged. So… Not to say "user fishing for reputation" ? Hmmm who can judge… they have got a poor 50 and would expect what ? Particularly on this SE : doubling ? Hah bha ! Should we mind ?

Comment: Relating https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/when-should-i-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question?rq=1 where the community (in 2014) as almost evenly split between "multiple answers" and "one larger answer".